# In difference-in-difference method, should I code treatment exposure as 0 or missing for pre treatment rounds?

Tags: paneldata, difference-in-difference

In my data, there are some pre-treatment rounds, and some post-treatment rounds. I use months of exposure to treatment in my analysis. So for post-treatment rounds, I have positive values for months of exposure. For pre-treatment rounds, months of exposure would be negative. I am confused whether I should code these negative months as zero or as missing.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Could you write the equations of estimation you are considering? It will help us evaluate your question better.

Comment: In general, you should have two dummy variables: one for "treated" and one for "post-treatment." If the unit is ever treated, then it takes a "1" for the "treated" variable. If it is never treated, it gets a "0." The DiD estimate, then, is an interaction between "Post x Treatment" (which only takes a value of "1" for the treated units after they're exposed to the treatment.) But as Michael Gmeiner says, more detail can help give more specific answers!